# Linux server acting as router for network switch (LAN party)

Tags: linux, debian, lan, switch

I'm going to be hosting a LAN party as part of a youth group and need to set up a small wired network (about 10 people) for the players to access the server where the game files are held for downloading (Just a simple apache server, I know how to do that) and also to connect to the game server. I'm going to have a 24 port network switch (a bit overkill, but that's what I'll have) and a server computer.

```
Diagram:        etc.
                +----PC
SERVER---SWITCH-+----PC
                +----PC
                etc.
```

The server will be running Linux (Probably Debian) and does not need to be connected to the internet. I'm not very experienced with networking but I'm sure knows what I'm talking about.

QUESTION: how do I configure something like this? Is it just plug-and-play? Do I need to use some specific software and configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you set up a DHCP server on that machine, because otherwise everyone need to set a static IP
Also, just use Ubuntu, its easy and has a LOT of documentation on how to set up services (like DHCP)

How to set up a DHCP server in Ubuntu? [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server)

Now also, i would HIGHLY recommend you use a SAMBA server for those game files!
Apache is made for websites, not hosting game files.

Now SAMBA is made to be used as a NAS, so in theory, you should be able to host game files on there.

How to set up a SAMBA server? [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21)

Also be aware that your machine should have an SSD of some sort to host those game files, if you use an HDD, you will get a MASSIVE bottleneck

And another piece of advice, from my own experience... build the whole thing a week before the event! if anything happens, or if you need to learn something extra, you will have plenty of time to do so :)

Comment: Just a DHCP server? cool. Since Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian, the HOWTO you linked should work on Debian too. Also, the Files should only have to be downloaded once and it's only about 500MB so I think a hard drive will be fine (I'm using my only SSD in my laptop).

Comment: For a LAN party? DHCP should be fine
Why? because the switch will take layer 2 of the OSI model
And the router will handle layer 3 :)

Comment: Just thought it would be harder. Glad it isn't :) I'll try it out when I get the switch.

Comment: About the game files, Sure ok, the HDD would be fine :)
I hope i answered your question!!
About "harder"... it will be hard... just make sure you set it up a week before the party

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer and I'll try it out when I can.